# Import excel into R from starting point until the end

Tags: r

I have to import an excel file into R. I need to import starting at line x and import everything after that. How do I demonstrate that in the code.

I have tried:

import <- read.xlsx("filename", "Sheet1", rowIndex = 13:end)
import <- read.xlsx("filename", "Sheet1", rowIndex = 13:)

and both of these threw errors, so I just ask for rows 13 to 200,000 which is bigger than it will ever be. How do I reference the last row when the last row is constantly changing depending on the dataset that I am using.

Comment: Please show the package used

Comment: If you use `readxl::read_excel`, it has a `skip` argument so you can set `skip = 12` and not worry about the last line.

Comment: But also, looking at the documentation for `xlsx::read.xlsx` (assuming that's the package you are using), it has a `startRow` argument you can use instead of `rowIndex`. Try `startRow = 13`.

Answer (score 1):

`xlsx::read.xlsx(..., startRow = 13, ...)` or `readxl::read_excel(..., skip = 12, ....)`